# Do we have any limited size of Git Repositories in Azure DevOps Service?

Tags: azure-devops

We are going to handle another team's work and move to use Azure DevOps Service instead of SVN.

They put everything in a single Git Repo. That made the Repo quiet large. Have no idea how large it is.

Per my understanding, Microsoft hold data in their own Azure SQL Database. If so, do we have any limited size of Git Repositories in Azure DevOps Service?

Could we pay additional if there's any way to increase that limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The individual file limit is **5GB** and the overall limit is **10GB** with Git Repo in Azure DevOps Service.

You can run `git count-objects -vH` in a command prompt, and look for the entry called "size-pack" to determine how large your repository is:

```
D:\my-repo>git count-objects -vH

count: 482
size: 551.67 KiB
in-pack: 100365
packs: 25
size-pack: 642.76 MiB   <-- size of repository
prune-packable: 83
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0 bytes
```

In uncommon circumstances, repositories may be larger than 10GB. For instance, the Windows repository is at least 300GB. For that reason, we do not have a hard block in place.

If your repository grows beyond 10GB, **consider using Git-LFS, VFS for Git, or Azure Artifacts to refactor your development artifacts**. Sorry, you may not be able to pay additional to increase this limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official information about git limitations and import suggestions here: [Git limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=azure-devops).